# sublime error occurs ,need to do what else?

Tags: sublimetext3

I already installed Sublime Text 3.... But it doesn't works properly.... Is there anything else to do?? Actually I'm fresher to sublime.So I need your help to continue... Besides of installing Sublime text I didn't installed any other thing.... I think is there something to install... That's why this happens.. What all steps are needed to install to run my sublime properly.. So please help me to solve.... Does every other version Sublime Text need this steps??
ADVANCE THANKS FOR YOUR KIND HELP...

Comment: Please show what you did and the error message.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You must first go to this url
https://packagecontrol.io/installation
From this site you will get the steps..You need to install first package control..Each version has its own package control..